# Start thread once another is running

Tags: c, pthreads

I start 3 pthreads and after running my application a few times I see that there is no exact order of the thread creation according to the order of the create statements.

How does one create another thread once a certain thread has started?

I still want to create the thread from the same "level" rather than creating the needed thread from inside the thread I want to start first.

Comment: Get the thread you're starting to set a concurrency object, that your main thread then waits for. Once that's been set, you know the first thread has started and you can start the second etc...

Comment: it's the inner nature of threads not to be order-deterministic, you should rearrange your code so that it doesn't matter !

Answer (score 1):

Threads do not have "levels" or parent/child relationship. All threads including the initial thread main runs in are peers. Any thread can call `pthread_join` on any other thread as long as the thread descriptor is valid and the thread is not detached.

If you do really need to enforce an ordering, the simplest tool for this is barriers (`pthread_barrier_wait`). On the other hand, condition variables are a good bit more powerful, but harder to use, and probably not needed for this situation.

Comment: I decided to have a global int set to 0 and then I set it to 1 inside the thread. So when it is set to 1, I start the other thread because in my main loop I have an if checking for == 1, then it starts the thread. I would rather use a built in function if it exists. barrier_wait doesnt seem to be correct for this.

Comment: Your solution is not correct. You cannot read variables modified by a different thread without an intervening synchronization operation, or the result is UB.

Comment: I used conditionals pthread_cond_wait etc. along with a mutex in the end. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can find interesting pthread signals and wait on condition variables.
Here are examples and the explanation.
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal

Answer (score 0):

If your platform supports it, I belive semget(), semop(), semctl() should handle this.  Just need to have the main process thread create and wait on a semaphore and have each thread semop() the semaphore once it is appropriate for the next thread in the sequence to be spawned.

See: http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc700/html/lr2/z2101576.htm

Answer (score 0):

Can you call call pthread_create() from the thread function?

pthread_create creates a thread, and as you have discovered, it doesn't call the thread function.  Basically your new thread is on the active thread list and the scheduler can give it a timeslice whenever it chooses.  Usually this is a couple ms, but can be longer.